# Wanting to split a 10/3 wire coming from a 30amp breaker

Tags: subpanel, 240v

From my main electrical panel I have a 30 amp 240v breaker with 10 gauge wire running to a shed. What is the safest and most economical way to split that wire in the shed into two?

Comment: Do you need two 240v/30a receptacles, or are you looking for 120v receptacles, or...?

Comment: A sub panel that has a rating equal or greater than 30 amps will do.  You can have a few circuits as long you do not exceed 30 amps total at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Economical: Change the breaker that feeds the wire to a two pole 20, and connect the wire in the shed to a [two pole light switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000LETGVY) to switch the black and red to serve as the required disconnect. Then use the black to white as one circuit and the red to white as the other.

I like and advise leaving the 30A feed and mounting a 30A+ panel and smaller breakers to feed multiple circuits, but then you no longer get the "multiwire branch circuit" exception and you have to add ground rods, and you are moving away from economical.

Answer (score 1):

best way would be a sub-panel for greatest flexibility, now and in the future. Obviously it would need to be at least a 30 amp sub, but that's pretty small. I'd double that to 60 amp sub.   It's perfectly fine with the NEC to go larger than needed, just not smaller.  There is a ton of info here on SE and on the web regarding installing subs.  Thanks to manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact I'm editing this answer to make SURE the OP knows he can't swap out a 30 amp breaker for a 60 amp breaker just bc it's feeding a 60 amp panel.  Breakers are intended to protect **installed wiring**.  10ga is 30 amp, period and must be protected by a 30 breaker.

One question:  Is the run a 3-wire or 4-wire run? If only 3-wire, you've got issues.   If 3-wire, how practical would it be to add a ground wire from the main panel to the shed?

Comment: The not counting ground does lead to confusion.  We who know, think of /3 or three wire as a silent plus ground.

Comment: *I'd double that to 60 amp sub.* Make it really clear that even though the subpanel is rated for 60A (or even has a 60A main or backfed breaker as a disconnect), your breaker in the main panel **must stay 30A** if you are using 10 AWG wire.